# Performing Linear search in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Write a Java program that stores 5 values in an array.
Ask the user to input a value to look for.
Perform a Linear Search to look for the inputted value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int value;
                        
        int [] array = {10, 5, 21, 16, 11};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the searched value");
        value=input.nextInt();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++);
        {
        if (array [i] == value);
        {
            System.out.println(value+ " is found at Index "+(i+1));
            {   
        if (i == array.length);
            System.out.println(value+ " is not in the list");
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to detect the errors in it. (PS I'm a beginner)
Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: And what is the problem? Wrong result, exception..?

Comment: You have extra semicolons after your `if`s.

Comment: `if (i == array.length)` will also never evaluate to true because your loop ends before this could happen (and `i` is scoped to the loop body)

Comment: also a `{` above `system.out.println(value+ " is found at Index "+(i+1));` and after the `if (i == array.length);` you have two consecutive `}`. Remove one after the if and the another above the System, are not nedded

Comment: Also remove the `;` after the `for`, this makes your loop body an empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int value;
                        
        int [] array = {10, 5, 21, 16, 11};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the searched value");
        value = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        int i = 0;
        while( i < array.length )
        {
          if (array[ i ] == value)
          {
            System.out.println(value+ " is found at Index "+(i+1));
            break;
          }
          i++;
        }
        if (i == array.length)
        {
          System.out.println(value+ " is not in the list");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you replace his for with while? Now i == array.length will always be true

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int value;

    int[] array = {10, 5, 21, 16, 11};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the searched value");
    value = input.nextInt();
    boolean isValueFound = false;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            isValueFound = true;
            index = i;

        }

    }

    if (isValueFound) {
        System.out.println(value + " is found at Index " + (index));
    } else {
        System.out.println(value + " is not in the list");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the general concept.  Keep the search and the reporting separate.  Use the iteration to find the index and then report what you find after the iteration is complete.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // gather the inputs
  int value = getUserInput();
  int[] array =  {10, 5, 21, 16, 11};

  // search for value in the array
  int valueIndex = -1; // negative index is a flag
  for (int index = 0  ; index < array.length ; ++index) {
    if (value == array[index]) {
      valueIndex = index;
      break;
    }
  }

  // report our finding!
  if (valueIndex < 0) {
    System.out.println(value + " is not in the list");
  } else {
    System.out.println(value + " was found at index " + valueIndex);
  }
}
```